# using imgix with html links for retina images

Tags: html, css, retina, imgix-js, imgix

I am using imgix to server my images. They have a great library for serving jpegs at just the right size and pixel density. But it doesn't work when I need to add links to those images.

Here's the fiddle & the code:
[jsfiddle.net/L95suygs/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/L95suygs/1/)

```
<style>
...
.feature-img {
    width:23%;
    margin:0 1% .5em;
    height:320px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
@media (max-width:1024px){
    .feature-img {
        width:48%;
        margin:0 1% .5em;
    }
}
@media (max-width:480px){
    .header-img{
        width:100%;
        margin:0 0 .5em 0;
    }
    .feature-img {
        width:100%;
        margin:0 0 .5em;
        height:200px;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="container" id="example1">
    <!-- Header Image -->
    <div class="header-img">
        <img class="imgix-fluid" data-src="//assets.imgix.net/examples/octopus.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces" >
    </div>
    <div class="feature-img">
        <a href="http://google.com"><img class="imgix-fluid" data-src="//assets.imgix.net/examples/jellyfish.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-img">
        <img class="imgix-fluid" data-src="//assets.imgix.net/examples/lionfish.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces">
    </div>
    <div class="feature-img">
        <img class="imgix-fluid" data-src="//assets.imgix.net/examples/clownfish.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces">
    </div>
    <div class="feature-img">
        <img class="imgix-fluid" data-src="//assets.imgix.net/examples/fin.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    updateOnResizeDown : true,
    updateOnPinchZoom : true,
    fitImgTagToContainerWidth: true,
    fitImgTagToContainerHeight: true,
    pixelStep : 10,
    onChangeParamOverride: function(w, h) {
        var dpr = Math.ceil(window.devicePixelRatio*10) /10;
            return {"txt": "w:" + w + " h:" +h + " dpr:" + dpr,
            "txtalign": "center,bottom",
            "txtsize": 20,
            "txtfont":"Helvetica%20Neue,bold",
            "txtclr":"ffffffff",
            "txtpad":20,
            "txtfit":'max',
            "exp":-2
        }
    }
};
imgix.onready(function() {
    imgix.fluid(options);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

### The Short Answer

Add something like the following to your CSS:

```
.feature-img > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This gives a definite size to your `<a>` tag, so its child image will be sized accordingly.

-- OR --

Change your HTML from this:

```
<div class="feature-img">
    <a href="http://google.com"><img class="imgix-fluid" data-src="..." ></a>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="feature-img">
    <img class="imgix-fluid" data-src="...">
</a>
```

This applies the `.feature-img` style that's already nicely defined to your `<a>` tag, rather than applying it to an unnecessary parent `<div>` and using the `<a>` tag as a child.

### The Long Answer

Marking an image as `imgix-fluid` means it will always size itself to fit its container's width (and in this case height, since you're passing in `fitImgTagToContainerHeight: true`).

In your standard case (`<img>` tag wrapped in a `<div>`), this behaves exactly as expected. Your `<div>` tags size themselves properly thanks to your CSS, and imgix.js ensures that the images inside it are the proper size, because you've marked them as `imgix-fluid`.

However, when you wrap an image in an `<a>` tag as you've done with the second image in the example, the `<img>`'s parent container is no longer the handsomely-sized `<div>`, it's now an `<a>` with no styling applied to it whatsoever. And, because `<a>` is an inline element by default, it has no inherent sizing of its own--inline elements size themselves to fit their contents. The `<a>` sizes itself to fit the `<img>` inside of it (which has no `src` attribute, and therefore will be sized to something small but inconsistent from browser to browser), and imgix.js sizes the image inside it to be as small as its parent `<a>`. It's kind of a chicken-and-egg problem, but it ends in disappointment instead of continuing indefinitely.

As stated above, there are two solutions you could use:

1. Simply apply some styles to your `<a>` tag. If you set it to `display:block;` and set `width` and `height` to `100%`, the anchor will automatically fill the space created by its parent `<div>` and consequently imgix.js will size the child `<img>` appropriately.
2. Ditch the parent `<div>` in this case and just make the `<a>` the container! Replacing the outer `<div>` with an `<a>` works perfectly, as long as you give the `<a>` the `feature-img` class.

For my money, the second approach seems cleaner and makes more sense.

Hope this helps!